# Is it possible for a single app to have two notifyicons?

Tags: c#, notifyicon

Is it possible for a single app to have two notifyicons?

How can this be done properly?

This will be our interim solution until we get to phase 2 where the app will be split into two.

Comment: @lubos: Qs without answers are not included in the stat. (For more details search on MSO.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible for a single app to have two notifyicons?

Yes. E.g. [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can (if you select the right options). So there is no Windows/Shell limitation.

Try having two [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) instances in one form, or two forms (could be hidden) each with one.